# Wikipedia API returns pageids not found in Wikipedia dump

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I have indexed Wikipedia version 2017-10-20 in a search engine, and I am using the publicly available Wikipedia Api http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php for finding articles in a specific category.

This API gives me back the pageids of the retrieved documents, however, I would like to map these page ids to my existing Wikipedia dump. It seems like these ids are not present. I would appreciate any advice on how to link them, and also from which version of Wikipedia are these pageids retrieved. Thank you!

Comment: It's really unclear what you are asking. Can you rephrase?